# Having issues with verifying if email exists in data base

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've creating a user management system. I want the php script to verify if email addresses exist already in the database. I can update user data. I can verify correct email format. The part of my script that isn't working is the part that checks if the email is already in use. Here is the part that doesn't work:

```
    if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])
    {

    $query_email = "
         SELECT
         from users
         where
         email = :email
    ";

    $query_goes = array(

    ':email' => $_POST['email']

    );
    try
    {

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query_email);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_goes);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) 
    {
        die("Email already in use...");
    }
```

Error it throws: Ouch, failed to run query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ 'tuskrr@fun.com' pour la clef 'email'

Comment: Your query is wrong. You need to select something. A column or `*`

Comment: I've fixed the query. I can't believe that I missed that. How can I avoid duplicate entries? This code above I only want to run if the admin changes the users email. If there are no changes it's skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select something. You can do `SELECT 1` since you're just checking whether the row exists or not and could care less to have physical data returned.

There will be no result if the email isn't there, there will be a result if there is.

```
$query_email = "
     SELECT
     1
     from users
     where
     email = :email
";
```

On another note, how would this ever execute:

`if($_POST['email'] !=$_POST['email'])`

In what case would a variable not be equal to itself?

I can't picture this logic even running to begin with. Your error is for a duplicate entry, which has nothing to do with any code you've provided. My guess is that it's skipping this code and you're going straight to your insert.

Maybe `if(isset($_POST['email']))` is what you want?

Comment: I'm going straight to an update query on the next line after this code. What can a do to avoid duplicate entries?

Comment: My logic behind the != is that email addresses are all different. if the email is changed it's no longer equal to itself the email is different. Example:  fun@fun.com gets changed to fun1@fun.com it's no longer equal to itself.

Comment: That doesn't make sense because there is no instance at any point in time where a variable will not equal itself. `$a=1; if($a!=$a) { /* this will never happen, ever, it's not physically possible */ }` A variable can be not equal to another variable, but **x is always equal to x** in mathematics and logic, you can change what x is, but that doesn't mean `x!=x`

Comment: Instead you should be storing the original email as a variable, say `$originalEmail`, then comparing `$_POST['email'] != $originalEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

Like juergen d said in comment, your query is wrong.
Since you only want to check if the email exist I suggest to get the email column instead of all.

```
$query_email = "
         SELECT <----- should be SELECT email
         from users
         where
         email = :email";
```

Like this

```
$query_email = "
     SELECT email
     from users
     where
     email = :email";
```